# javascript make function parameters dynamic

Tags: javascript, html

so I am trying to include payment API checkout on my order.html page, however, you must add a script in the head of HTML document.  in the script, you must specify the subtotal amount as a number, but I need this value to be dynamic. the "stotal" is the subtotal amount.  I need to set subtotal to whatever the "stotal" is.  How I do this?

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function paymentApi() {
      V.init({
        apikey: "",
        encryptionKey: "",
        paymentRequest: {
          currencyCode: "USD",
          subtotal: "11.00"
        }
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="sub-total">
    <strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal"></span>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change subtotal to get the value from the html as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function paymentApi(){
    V.init( {
    apikey: "",
    encryptionKey: "",
    paymentRequest:{
        currencyCode: "USD",
        subtotal: document.getElementById('stotal').innerText //Here
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's better to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerTextt) instead of `innerText`. Probably there is no difference in this case but I prefer to always use `textContent` - I don't think I've found a reason to get `innerText` only. Although I do find it particularly annoying how `innerText` is the better name, since it is easy to see it as the "plain text" version of `innerHTML`.

Comment: In this case, i suppose he only wanted stuff that was human readable. If there's a script tag, you wouldn't want to showing up

Answer (score -4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function paymentApi(){
    var subtotal = parseFloat($("#stotal").text());

    V.init( {
    apikey: "",
    encryptionKey: "",
    paymentRequest:{
        currencyCode: "USD",
        subtotal: subtotal
    }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I don't think jquery is necessary for such a simple job.

Comment: i have used for get only integer value parseInt()

Comment: It could also be a floating point value. 11.23$ would show up as 11. Not the intended behaviour

Comment: parseFloat get only integer and float value. no nees to get any string like $. so we use this

Comment: parsefloat will not parse values with $ sign at the beginning as the case maybe parseFloat("$1.2") = NaN

Comment: why to assume that subtotal div contain $ sign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194374/discussion-between-amarat-and-somesh-mukherjee).

Comment: if it doesn't, then parseFloat is unecessary